# What time do NOS IFR Charts expire?

Tags: faa, aeronautical-charts

My charts have 13 September 2018 on them.  What time do they expire?

I thought at Midnight that night local time, but have been unable to find any corroborating evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In FAA-land the AIRAC cycle effective time is 0901Z. Your old charts were valid until 13 September 2018, 0900Z, the new ones are valid since 13 September 2018 0901Z.

I can't find the regulation that says it's always the case, but Google FAA 0901Z and you see that will give a ton of new charts / publications.

Here is a [Jeppesen publication](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/04/revision_date_vs_effective_date.pdf) that explains the interpretation of the effective date.

Answer (score 1):

Unofficial answer is 23:59z if anyone else has the same question.  Some FAA personal may or may not allow it till 12:59 Local.

The FAA inspector I spoke with could not provide me documentation on how he came up with that answer.

If you were slapped by the FAA for having expired plates on the day of, they probably were out to get you or your company and you may have a chance to get out of it since it's vague as to to when they really do expire.

Answer (score 0):

Well, legally speaking, in a world where an FAA inspector is waiting to jump out from behind a tree to nail you for an infraction, it would be safe to say 23:59 Zulu on the 13th.  But in the practical world, end of the day on the 13th where you live should suffice.  In any case, I don't believe there is a regulation in the US that even requires a current chart for VFR flight.  So relax.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it's for an IFR flight for a Part 135 Carrier, so it matters.

Comment: Are you concerned about getting dinged by your Capt or someone else in management doing a spot inspection of some kind?  It's still not like an FAA inspector's going to jump out from behind a bush with clock in hand.

Comment: FAA Inspectors.
I am the Captain. I ended up printing out new charts and plates from fltplan.com.  
I fly into a major airport FAA inspectors are around all the time, some I know by name now that's how often they are around.
I had one come up to me today since he heard we were late getting our NOS plates and charts.  
It would have had a problem if I didn't print them out this morning prior to my flight.  
I also cannot use ForeFlight or similar unless it's been approved by the FAA and it is in my companies OpSpecs.

Comment: Holy crap. At least that was a next day thing.  I originally thought it was just a VFR thing you were asking about but in that case the 23:59Z on-the-date limit is your limit I'd say if it came down to getting busted or not.  I suppose you could ask an inspector if local midnight is ok, but I'll bet you'll get different answers with different inspectors.